# Call script function in html body tag

Tags: javascript, html, document-body

here i try to call a script in body tag but it does not work.. and here i want to show when somebody open website then image display as a pop up without click anywhere

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           function openWin(img){

               var popup_window = window.open("images/dubai.png", "_blank ", "width=200, height=200");
window.onclick = function () {
        popup_window.close();
        </script>



</head>
<body onload="openWin()">
</body>
```

when i debug then image is not display as a pop up.. so where is the mistake? and how to resolve this?

Comment: If you add a `alert('Test')` statement inside the openWin function do you see an alert?

Comment: Is this the whole code? Because there are closing curly brackets missing at the end of your script tag

Comment: It looks like openWin needs an argument and isnt getting one also.

Comment: yes this is whole code

Comment: @moshikaro i add this alert but not works

Comment: Do not put inline javascript in your html... bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Popups are annoying, so browsers will only open them in response to a user action (such as clicking on a button). The document loading (i.e. the `load` event which you reference with the `onload` attribute) is not a user action, so the call to `open` is blocked.

The specific rules for when a popup is allowed can be found [in the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup).

---

You also have a syntax error in your code (although it may be a transcription error when you created the question). You are missing `};` from just before `</script>`. This should be indicated in the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: ok i modify this but this is no work also.....  <script type="text/javascript">

           function openWin(img){

               var popup_window = window.open("images/dubai.png", "_blank ", "width=200, height=200");
               window.onclick = function()
            

       {
        popup_window.close();
         }
     }
   </script>

Comment: @capricongurl — That doesn't do anything. You never call the function.

Comment: i call function in body tag

Comment: @capricongurl — So still onload? See the first two paragraphs of this answer.

Comment: but i dont want to add button event or anything click like this... i just want to display image as a pop up

Comment: @capricongurl — Too bad. People hate automatic popups. Browsers don't let authors create them.

Comment: @capricongurl — Go lobby the authors of the HTML specification and ask them to make the WWW more horrible for everyone because you have a requirement then.